# Where is the identity function shell command?

Tags: shell

I am looking for the shell command that prints its standard input to standard output. What is this command called? I'm quite surprised I can't find it.

Comment: this is an useless command - when print it unmodified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal utility for this is [`cat(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat).

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Comment: Fortunately the link is easily replaced with running `man 1 cat` at the shell command line.

Answer (score -1):

printing the stdin to stdout is possible with many commands:

```
sed <file
```

or

```
grep '' <file
```

or

```
awk '//' <file
```

or

```
perl -ple '' < file
```

or

```
tail +0 < file
```

or the usual

```
cat < file
```

and in the above form - each is useless